# Speeding up path calculation of many particles using Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I am trying to calculate the evolution of the position of many particles using Python. Ultimately I will have many particles (on the order of 10000) being calculated over around 100000 time-steps. Since I am trying at all costs to avoid having to use Fortran, I am trying to speed up the process.

The equation I am trying to solve is

```
d X_i/dt = u
d Y_i/dt = v
```

So ideally I would work with arrays with two dimensions: one to change between particles and another to change between `x`, and `y`. So if I had 100 particles, I'd have a `100x2` array.

A part of the problem comes because `scipy.integrate.odeint` only takes 1-dimensional arrays, so I have to flatten my initial conditions, split it inside my derivative function (`RHS_im`), and then flatten it again when outputting, which is slow (this accounts for about 20% of the `RHS_im` call).

I can do it in an ugly way. Here's a MWE that I put up

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
from scipy.integrate import odeint

x=np.arange(2.5, 500, 5)
y=np.arange(2.5, 500, 5)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='xy')

U=np.full_like(X, -0.1)
V=0.2*np.sin(2*np.pi*X/200)

tend=100
dt=1
tsteps=np.arange(0, tend, dt)

#------
# Create interpolation
U_int = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y), U.T)
V_int = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y), V.T)
#------

#------
# Initial conditions
x0=np.linspace(200,300,5)
y0=np.linspace(200,300,5)
#------


#------
# Calculation for many
def RHS_im(XY, t):
    X, Y = np.split(XY, 2, axis=0)
    pts=np.array([X,Y]).T
    return np.concatenate([ U_int(pts), V_int(pts) ])
XY0 = np.concatenate([x0, y0])
XY, info = odeint(RHS_im, XY0, tsteps[:-1], args=(), hmax=dt, hmin=dt, atol=0.1, full_output=True)
X, Y = np.split(XY, 2, axis=1)
```

Is there a way to avoid the split process?

Furthermore, although I have chosen `odeint` to integrate this system, I am not committed to the choice. I would easily change if there is another function that does this faster (even with a simple Euler scheme). I just didn't find any. (The same thing goes for the interpolation scheme, which is roughly 80% of the time that `RHS_im` takes).

**EDIT**

Improved the splitting process a bit (by using `np.split`) but the overall program still needs improvement.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you starting off with initial x,y conditions on a grid that is 5x5, then interpolating the u,v values for a grid that is 100x100 in your derivative function?

Comment: @binaryfunt Nope, the grid is already `100x100`. I think you're confusing `arange` with `linspace`.

Comment: But when you set `x0=np.linspace(200,300,5)`, `x0` has a length of 5

Comment: @binaryfunt I understand what you mean now. That is the number of particles. I'm giving 5 initial conditions, one for each particle. I'm not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: Do you need to use the grid interpolation?

Comment: @alexdor I think I need to use *some* interpolation. Because the displacement will never coincide exactly with another node on the grid. I can't think of a way to do this without interpolation

Comment: I meant could you evaluate u and v directly in RHS_im rather than using a grid

Comment: @alexdor this is just a MWE. The actual velocity field is collected data. But you're right in that I should have specified that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification on your MWE. I was able to get the MWE to run about 50% faster by combing `U_int` and `V_int` into `UV_int` and by changing the layout of XY so that np.reshape can be used instead of np.split. Both of these change help access memory inplace and contiguously.

```
x_grid=np.arange(2.5, 500, 5)
y_grid=np.arange(2.5, 500, 5)

x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(x_grid, y_grid, indexing='xy')

u_mesh=(np.full_like(x_mesh, -0.1))
v_mesh=(0.2*np.sin(2*np.pi*x_mesh/200))
uv_mesh = np.stack([u_mesh.T, v_mesh.T], axis=-1)

tend=100
dt=1
tsteps=np.arange(0, tend, dt)

#------
# Create interpolation
UV_int = RegularGridInterpolator((x_grid, y_grid), uv_mesh)
#------

#------
# Initial conditions
npart = 5
x0=np.linspace(200,300,npart)
y0=np.linspace(200,300,npart)

XY_pair = np.reshape(np.column_stack([x0, y0]), (2*npart))
#-----


def RHS_im(XY, t):        
    return np.reshape(UV_int(np.reshape(XY, (npart, 2))), (npart*2))

XY, info =  odeint(RHS_im, XY_pair, tsteps[:-1], args=(), hmax=dt, hmin=dt, atol=0.1, full_output=True)
```